# Trying to introduce a simple new condition to a JOIN query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite and I had someone help me construct this JOIN query which works quite well, but now I need to add another condition but I am having trouble introducing it to the query without it breaking.

In both tables used in the JOIN there is a column called EventId and I want to introduce the simple condition...

```
WHERE EventId = 123456
```

Below you can see a working example of the query itself along with two comments where I have tried to introduce the new condition and failed (because I'm bad at SQL).

```
SELECT t.MicrosoftId, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'necktie' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'necktie',
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'shirt' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'shirt',
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'suit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'suit',
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'man' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'man',
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'male' 
FROM TagsMSCV t 
        /* <---- WHERE t.EventId = 123456 (fails here...) */
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT i.MicrosoftId
FROM Images i 
GROUP BY i.MicrosoftId) i 
ON i.MicrosoftId = t.MicrosoftId 
WHERE t.name IN ('necktie','shirt','suit','man','male') 
        /* <---- AND WHERE t.EventId = 123456 (fails here too...) */
GROUP BY t.MicrosoftId
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how the query fails? Are you getting an error you can share?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed I was making an obvious error due to my inexperience. The only message I get is 'syntax error' so I must not be allowed put a WHERE condition in those two places I tried, or else I'm missing a comma or a bracket somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below

```
select t1.* from   ( SELECT t.MicrosoftId, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'necktie' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'necktie',
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'shirt' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'shirt',
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'suit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'suit',
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'man' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'man',
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'male' 
    FROM TagsMSCV t WHERE t.EventId = 123456 
  and name IN ('necktie','shirt','suit','man','male') group by t.MicrosoftId 
  ) t1
```

You did mistake to create subquery and as 2nd subquery no need group by as there no aggregate function used

Comment: You are correct!. Actually I just realised someone edited the database since this query was made. The table called 'TagsMSCV' now contains all the columns (e.g. MicrosoftId, EventId and name). Does this mean the query can be simplified with no JOIN to the 'Images' table?

Comment: @AzzyDude so far i dont think image table is necessary so you can remove it from join

Comment: Yes, you are correct. How would I remove the Image table join from the above query?

Comment: @AzzyDude check i edited though after edited there is no need of subquery

Answer (score 1):

It should be in `WHERE` section, but without second `WHERE` keyword:

```
SELECT t.MicrosoftId, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'necktie' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'necktie',
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'shirt' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'shirt',
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'suit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'suit',
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'man' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'man',
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'male' 
FROM TagsMSCV t 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT i.MicrosoftId
FROM Images i 
GROUP BY i.MicrosoftId) i 
ON i.MicrosoftId = t.MicrosoftId 
WHERE t.name IN ('necktie','shirt','suit','man','male') 
AND t.EventId = 123456
GROUP BY t.MicrosoftId
```

Comment: You are correct!. Actually I just realised someone edited the database since this query was made. The table called 'TagsMSCV' now contains all the columns (e.g. MicrosoftId, EventId and name). Does this mean the query can be simplified with no JOIN to the 'Images' table?